# "INSERT or UPDATE in table \"devices\" violates foreign key constraint \"devices_typeId_fkey\""

Tags: javascript, postgresql

When trying to add an element to the table, the following error occurs: `"INSERT or UPDATE in table \"devices\" violates foreign key constraint \"devices_typeId_fkey\""`. Why does it occur and how can it be corrected?

Here is my model for the given table in sequelize.

```
const Device = sequelize.define('device', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false},
    price: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    rating: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
    img: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
})
```

Here I send a request to create fields in the table, and this is where the error comes out

```
const uuid = require('uuid')
const path = require('path');
const {Device, DeviceInfo} = require('../models/models')
const ApiError = require('../error/ApiError');

class DeviceController {
    async create(req, res, next) {
        try {
            let {name, price, brandId, typeId, info} = req.body
            const {img} = req.files
            let fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg"
            img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName))
            const device = await Device.create({name, price, brandId, typeId, img: fileName});
            return res.json(device)
        } catch (e) {
            next(ApiError.badRequest(e.message))
        }
    }
```

Here is the POST request in Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2QSe.png)

Comment: It basically means that you've got a foreign key - the value you're trying to enter doesn't exist in (I'm guessing) the `types` table

Answer (score 0):

when you insert device you are passing typeId.
typeId is a foreign key in Device table which is referenced from Device Type table. there should be a primary key record with the value of typeId in Device Type table.

Comment: That is, in const Device (my model) should I add new fields typeId, brandId?

Comment: yes, your table must be having those two fields

Comment: I added these fields and still the same error, maybe there is some other reason? I have dependencies on a given table

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy UlbiTv tutorials as well
I had the same problem, that's how I found your video

so the trouble was in your request to database. I have fixed it, in my case I was setting a non existing `typeId` in a body. I didn't catch the moment when my `types table` started to be like `"{id: 1, ...} , {id: 6, ...}"`, but I was making a request to create a device with `typeId === 2` , but I had no such `id`
that's all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).